# Not able to place my TextView right

Tags: android

Can anyone help me with placing my undertitle right under the title? 
I'm relatively new to android programming and sorry for my bad english :D

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listIcon"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listTextDescription"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Undertitle" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: What's wrong with this XML? Can you provide a description of what you're getting as compared to what you want?

Comment: @Nacho Problem already solved, but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, just change your layout from **LinearLayout** to **RelativeLayout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listIcon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listIcon"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/listTextDescription"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/listText"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:text="Undertitle" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/listIcon"
        android:padding="8dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:src="@drawable/facebook"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listText"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Title" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/listTextDescription"
            android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Undertitle" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```